# Certainly Certain

Tags: riddle, word

The following adjectives apply to a certain noun.

> Complex
>   Alternative
>   Exempt
>   Deductive
>   Dependent
>   Fuzzy
>   Critical

And most of all, `Certain`.

What is the noun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

> tax?

Complex

> complex tax: many rules.

Alternative

> alternative tax: where the tax rules allow choice
>  ADDED: perhaps a shortened form of [Alternative Minimum Tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_minimum_tax)

Exempt

> tax exempt: no tax payable

Deductive

> tax deductive: reduces the amount of tax payable (a tax deduction is a reduction in the income subject to tax)

Dependent

> dependent tax: the tax is conditional on (some) criteria. (A dependent is also the label given to [persons who entitle a taxpayer to claim a dependency exemption](https://apps.irs.gov/app/understandingTaxes/hows/tax_tutorials/mod04/tt_mod04_01.jsp).)

Fuzzy

> fuzzy tax: the amount of tax raised (or the applicability of criteria) is imprecise

Critical

> critical tax: the country depends on it

And most of all, Certain.

> "Our new Constitution is now established, and has an appearance that promises permanency; but in this world nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes."
>  [- Benjamin Franklin, quoted in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_taxes_%28idiom%29)

Comment: Your answer is good, but your reasoning is less than persuasive.

Comment: @LN6595 Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at your reasoning for alternative, deductive, dependent. Is there something in the rules of <target answer> that could better explain those three.

Comment: @LN6595 Do you like the edited version better?

Answer (score 11):

Answer:

> Logic

Complex

> Complex Logic: mental processes that facilitate the understanding of complicated problems using logic.

Alternative

> Alternative Logic: the name given to formal systems that differ in a significant way from standard logical systems such as propositional and predicate logic.

Exempt

> Exempt Logic: 'A priori' knowledge or justification as independent of experience.

Deductive

> Deductive Logic: the process of reasoning from one or more statements to reach a logically certain conclusion.

Dependent

> Dependent Logic: a logical formalism which adds dependence atoms to the language of first-order logic.

Fuzzy

> Fuzzy Logic: an approach based on degrees of truth rather than true or false.

Critical

> Critical Logic: clear, rational thinking involving critique.

Certain

> Certain Logic: there's a certain logic to this..

Comment: I think this fits the best

Answer (score 10):

You have to be talking about

> My daughter

Complex

> Way too complex for me to understand

Alternative

> Music, hairstyle: absolutely

Exempt

> Here you must be referring to her attitude to household chores.

Deductive

> Yes. It's like there's a hole in my wallet.

Dependent

> Come income tax time, that's what goes on the form

Fuzzy

> Particularly under her bed. Don't get me started.

Critical

> You really do know her, don't you?

And most of all, Certain.

> Certain about every topic on earth.

What do I win?

Comment: This is so good my friend

Answer (score 7):

Could it be:
EDIT Thanks to @feelinferrety

> Reasoning

Because then we have:

> Complex Reasoning
>  Alternative Reasoning
>  Exempt Reasoning
>  Deductive Reasoning
>  Dependent Reasoning
>  Fuzzy Reasoning
>  Critical Reasoning
>  Certain Reasoning

Comment: Ok... And why "Most of all" certain?

Comment: @LN6595  *Reason* is the most of all *certain* answer because it's the most *reasonable* answer for *certain*!

Comment: Your answer + `-ing` may be a better fit.

Comment: First thing that came to my head... stop stealing answers! Pressing charges!

Answer (score 2):

> Decision

Please refer the explanation below:

Complex

> A decision can be made based on considering complex scenarios.

Alternative

> Decision may have alternatives.

Exempt

> Decision is not subjected to particular reason always.

Deductive

> Decision can be made after making assertions and hence deducting other scenarios.

Dependent

> Decision can be dependent also based on situation.

Fuzzy

> Decisions can be at times vague, like fuzzy decisions are made in implementing fuzzy logic.

Critical

> Decision is critical as it may be subjected to consequences.

Certain

> You are certain when you make a decision. So above all, decision is certain.